# How can I get products with specified attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, collection

In my project trying to **pull product from selected category which have a specific attribute value.**

```
$currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    //->addFieldToFilter(???????) //category id ????
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name','price','special_price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('showme',array('eq' => 'Yes'))
    ->load();
```

or within whole categories tree (I mean category and its childrens)

I stuck and don't really have an idea.

How to achieve it ?

Then check if there is more than one then pick the first one and "show".

EDIT:

I just forgotten to add: two parameters must be checked, "if showme and category" then show :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `showme` attribute is a yes/no attribute then you need to call the following:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('showme', 1);
```

The problem in your case is that you're calling `addAttributeToSelect` which will not let you filter the results.

If you need to filter by category you can call

```
->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

where `$category` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` that corresponds to the category to filter.

Comment: Thank you Raph, it works even as it is but .... I would like to add filter by category so it should display products within current category and with "showme" = 1

Comment: @RobertA. see my edited answer